# How do I display what's in an object?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and would like to know how to display what is in an object I created.
This is my code:

```
function removeDuplicates(num) {
    var x, // x is the index of the array
    len = num.length,
    out = [],
    obj = {};

    for (x = 0; x < len; x++) {
        obj[num[x]] = 0;  
        console.log(x);
        console.log(obj[num[x]]);
        console.log(num[x]);
        // first run [x] = 0 
        // obj[num[x]] = 0
        // the push below writes out Ford
        // second run x = 1
        // obj[num[x]] = 0 
        // the push below overwrites the first Ford
        // third run x = 2
        // obj[num[x]] = 0
        // the push below writes out GMC
        // fourth run x = 3
        // obj[num[x]] = 0
        // the push below writes out Chevy
        // fifth run x = 4
        // obj[num[x]] = 0
        // the push below overwrites the first Chevy
        // etc
    }

    for (x in obj) {
        console.log(obj[x]);
        console.log("push loop");
        console.log(obj);
        out.push(x);
    }
    return out;
}

var theNum = ['Ford','Ford','GMC','Chevy','Chevy','Toyota','Ford'];
result=removeDuplicates(theNum);

console.log(theNum);
console.log(result);
```

I thought the `console.log(obj[]);` statement would display it, but all it shows is `object Object`.

Comment: `const removeDuplicates = arr => [...new Set(arr)];` - much better.

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))` or use a better console.

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Jonas, thanks for response.  What console do you recommend?  I tried your suggestion and I get this:  "Error: uncaught ReferenceError json is not defined"

Comment: @RufusBertrand — Jonas said `JSON` not `json`.

Comment: I changed to JSON, error gone now, but console doesn't display anything.

Comment: Have you tried console.dir(obj)?

Comment: Paula, I'm using Google

Comment: Kaashan, I tried "console.dir(obj)" but nothing.

Comment: If I do "console.log([x])" I get 'Ford', 'Chevy', etc for each loop.

Comment: thanks Danyal!  It worked when I ran it in Google > Developer Tools!  Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `console.log(obj)` should display a valid result

You could try stringifying the object as well

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Another thing you could try it to open your `chrome dev tools > console`, and then type `obj` there, you can further inspect the key/value properties held by the object

Comment: Danyal, I tried both and still nothing.  I'm using JSEditor on Google browser.

Comment: @RufusBertrand I just tried JSEditor & it seems to be working fine. Another thing you could try it to open your chrome dev tools > console, and then type obj there, you can further inspect the key/value properties held by the object.

Comment: Danyal, it worked!  So should I try a different console, or maybe I'm using an older version of JSEditor?

Comment: @RufusBertrand It sometimes happens with online compilers, they have some of the functionality overwritten. If this solved your problem then feel free to mark the answer as verified.

Comment: Done!  Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest chrome, then type `console.log(obj)` in the console.
The console will show you a object tree which all properties and sub properties shown in it. Not all object can be stringified, such as the object with recursive property. The good console also show the method and dom tree of node.